# iptables allow http incoming connections, state NEW, ESTABLISHED

Tags: iptables

Could somebody explain me, why it works:

```
administrador@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L INPUT
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source       destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere     anywhere            tcp dpt:www state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere     anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

and this doesn't:

```
administrador@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L INPUT
target     prot opt source       destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere     anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere     anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I'd rather say that second rule is more restricted. firewall has to check state of every packet, so why when I want to check web server availability, second option doesn't work? I mean machine can't connect with server.

Comment: Both should work. There must be something you are not showing which makes a difference. iptables-save gives full and much more readable output.

Answer (score 2):

The former rule employs connection tracking, the latter does not. The connection tracking entries are needed for the reply packets to get through. When the connection tracking system allows a packet in that establishes a connection or logical association, an automatic, temporary reflexive rule is created to allow the reply packets out.